# How to find the eigenvalues of this matrix, which has zeros on the diagonal and 1's elsewhere, without computing the characteristic polynomial,

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I don't think that computing the characteristic polynomial is the way to proceed for this problem.  Also, the size of this matrix C is just given as "nxn".

So, instead, I can look at the matrix *I+C*. Then this is a matrix of all 1's.

We know that this matrix is rank-deficient and so has determinant = 0.

Then I have that

$$det[I+C]$$
$$= det[C+I]$$
$$=det[C-(-1)I]$$
$$=0$$

The last equality shows that -1 is an eigenvalue of the original matrix C, which is what I wanted.

But, how do I know its multiplicity?

And, how do I know whether there are any more eigenvalues of C?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following
$$C\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix}=(n-1)\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Thus $n-1$ is also an eigen value.

**Multiplicity of $\lambda =-1$**

You already have that $\lambda=-1$ is an eigen value. Observe that $\text{rank }(C+I)=1$, thus null space of $C+I$ has dimension $n-1$. In other words, eigen space corresponding to the eigen value $\lambda=-1$ is spanned by $n-1$ linearly independent vectors. Thus multiplicity is $n-1$.

Moreover $\text{trace }C=0$ implies that sum of the eigen values must be $0$.

Thus the eigen values are $\lambda =\underbrace{-1,-1, \ldots -1}_{n-1 \text{ times}}, n-1$.

Comment: Hi @AnuragA, I like this nice intuitive argument, but I have a few follow-up questions: since sum of eigenvalues = trace = sum of diagonal elements, then the multiplicity of the eigenvalues really is its algebraic multiplicity, i.e., the number of times it shows up on a diagonalized matrix, *if* the matrix were diagonalizable.

Comment: Here you showed the geometric multiplicity for -1 is (n-1).  But geometric mult $\le$ algebraic multiplicity, so we haven't said for sure yet that it is definitely (n-1), unless the operator were diagonalizable in which case the multiplicities are equal.  Also what can we say about the multiplicity of the other eigenvalue (n-1)?  Not much, it seems like.  But what you showed *agrees* with trace(C) = sum of eigenvalues = 0.

Comment: So, I'm pretty sure we have the multiplicities correct, although not fully justified, though?  Feel free to comment further on this, if you'd like.  I might have possibly just overlooked a simple fact.  The end goal is to just compute determinant of C = product of eigenvalues.  So, I think we pretty much have all information... *except* for the multiplicity of the eigenvalues....

Comment: Actually, by your argument, there *can't* be any more eigenvectors, and hence eigenvalues.  You have found (n-1) linearly independent eigenvectors for -1, and one linearly independent eigenvector for (n-1); this forms a basis for $R^n$ already, and so this is a full set of linearly independent eigenvectors.  Then the (n-1) geometric multiplicity is forced to agree with the algebraic multiplicity for -1, I think.  And so your answer is complete, I think :-).  Thanks so much @AnuragA.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v=\pmatrix{1\\\vdots\\1}$. Then $C=vv^T-I$. So the characteristic polynomial of $C$ is
$$
p(\lambda)=|\lambda I-C|=|(\lambda+1) I-vv^T|=(\lambda+1)^n-Tr(vv^T)(\lambda+1)^{n-1}=(\lambda+1)^n-n(\lambda+1)^{n-1}=(\lambda+1)^{n-1}(\lambda-n+1)
$$
for $vv^T$ is a Rank-$1$ matrix and all principal minors above $2$ are $0$.

Thus eigenvalues of $C$ are $-1$ with multiplicity of $n-1$ and $n-1$ with multiplicity of $1$.

Comment: Hi @hermes - is it -1 and not 1 for the first eigenvalue?

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much @hermes :-)